# Python function defining -- invalid syntax?

Tags: python, function

I am writing a function that takes an input that calls two other functions. I've had no problem writing the two other functions but for some reason I'm getting an error message writing the third, having to do with the syntax.

```
def get_class_average(students):
    results=[]
    for student in students:
        x=get_average(student)
        results.append(x)
    return average(results)
```

and I get an error code: 
    `def get_class_average(students):
      ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

What am I missing? There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the way I wrote def.

Comment: well your tabs are all messed (in this question)up try `python -tt my_script.py` which will check for mixed tabs and spaces

Comment: That was only here on stackoverflow, I forgot to check my tabs when pasting here. I fixed it here, but my question was answered.

Answer (score 3):

Check the line before you define your def and make sure your syntax is correct for ending the statement.

Comment: That was it-- I forgot to delete the line before. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Every line after the first needs a tab.

```
def get_class_average(students):
     results=[]
     for student in students:
         x=get_average(student)
     results.append(x)
     return average(results)
```

Comment: I suspect that this is an artifact of how he copied and pasted it to SO ... (not that it rules out indentation issues as his problem) (especially since the error would be on the `results=[]` line if his indentation really matched his question indentation

Comment: That was how I had it written, I didn't think to check the formatting when I pasted here. I'll update it in the question, but jasgrider was totally correct.

Comment: You are probably right but just to be safe I thought I would mention it. I don't see any other issues without more code.